# Is there any way to make a ZF2 database adapter return column values in the appropriate data type?

Tags: sql, zend-framework2, zend-db

Is there any way to make a ZF2 database adapter return column values in the appropriate data type, or does it always return data as strings?

Something like this (where `$statement` is a `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement`):

```
$rows = $statement->execute();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $price = $row['price'];
}
```

`$price` is always a string, even though price is defined to be a float in the database.

Also, even if the answer is that MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite database adapters always return strings, would the answer be different for a different kind of database adapter?

Comment: In ZF2 its called Hydration and you do this using [`Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html). Possibly [this part of my documentation rewrite](https://github.com/manuakasam/ZF2_3_QuickStart_Rewrite/pull/11/files) can help you out.

Comment: Is there a reason you need specific types? PHP is loosely typed for a reason. To answer your question, AFAIK, other adapters will also return strings.

Comment: It's not a real requirement for me, but strings do serialize differently than numbers--I wind up with a couple of extra quotation marks.